# Trouble configuring virtual hosts on apache2

Tags: configuration, apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to configure two sites running on the same apache server with virtualhosts. Somehow whatever i try to configure apache has always problems with my config. Here is the configuration file

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 172.16.10.2:80
NameVirtualHost 172.16.10.2:8080

<VirtualHost 172.16.10.2:80>
   ServerName be.wincars.local
   DocumentRoot /var/www/wincarsbe
   CustomLog /var/www/logs/wincarsbe.log combined
   ErrorLog /var/www/logs/wincarsbe.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.16.10.2:8080>
   ServerName com.wincars.local
   DocumentRoot /var/www/wincarscom
   CustomLog/var/www/logs/wincarscom.log combined
   ErrorLog /var/www/logs/wincarscom.log
</VirtualHost>
```

When i try to restart apache, here is what I get:

[image: apache output]

Comment: try using ServerAlias

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Listen 80
....
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName be.wincars.local
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName com.wincars.local
...
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also try make Apache dump out information about configured VirtualHosts:

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```